# XML file as model for django project

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a XML file that is managed by other programs, I am writing a web service such that users are able to query this file. In essence i am using a xml based database instead of using sql as the model database in Django.

how do i do this? all the tutorials that i find use a sql database in the backend. is there a way to use the xml file as a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a package to do just this available [here](http://djangorestmodel.sourceforge.net/).  I haven't tried it, but looking through the source, it seems to be doing pretty much what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Also the [django-xml](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-xml) app gives you a *Model* interface to your XMLs.

Answer (score 0):

Use [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) with [`lxml`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/xpathxslt.html#xpath) to find specific nodes within the document.