# Django with XML or JSON files as database back-end

Tags: xml, database, django, json

I was looking for some database back-end for Django that could use XML or JSON file or files as source of data. Data can be read-only (only selects, no inserts and no updates). So this is first question - Is there something like this?
As an workaround I thought of using SQLite database that is used as back-end for Django and populated through some external parser.
Or it would be better to use Django deserialize technique to fill in database?

Comment: Maybe [this command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model) helps you

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511091/xml-file-as-model-for-django-project

Comment: This [DjangoRESTModel](http://djangorestmodel.sourceforge.net/) model is more complicated than needed but I think it can be reworked to use local xml. Also thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you're far better off using SQLite, it is easier to query by far and it works with the framework instead of against it. It sounds like you could get away with calling [`loaddata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata) in conjunction with a real database of your choice.

BUT if you really want to do something like use JSON, then I'd recommend looking at [this article](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/04/Writing-a-non-relational-Django-backend). It isn't a 1-to-1 map with what you're looking to do, but it has all of the basic steps in a way which is not far from what you're trying to do (after all, most non-relational databases are JSON based).

Answer (score 1):

For XML you can use [django-xml](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-xml)