# XML Backend for Django-Project

Tags: python, xml, django

I am creating a web application with Django. It's planned to be a SOAP-like architecture, and therefore i am using **REST** to communicate with the server.

> However, i want to create a XML database instead of PostgreSQL.

**Is there any extension of the Django framework which provides this feature?**

Or how would an approach look like? Any "good practice" there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511091/xml-file-as-model-for-django-project

Comment: Thank's, but i thought since it's two years old there must be a newer approach?

Comment: What exactly means "XML database"? An XML file that is on each operation opened, modified and saved? Or PostgreSQL/Oracle/DB2 with XML types? Or native XML database like BaseX? And what is the relationship of XML database and SOAP or REST?

Comment: Yeah, REST and SOAP is out of context, sorry. I just wanted to describe my app in more detail. A customer is filling out a web form, and then the data is saved as an XML file. This file should be stored in a XML database like BaseX.